# Is there a shortcut to insert the pipe operator (%>%) into databricks?

Tags: r

What is the shortcut to insert the pipe operator (%>%) into databricks? For RStudio, it is ctrl+shift+m, which doesn't work in databricks.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I assume you've looked in https://docs.databricks.com/index.html